# JSF error "Expected a child component type ... Found null."

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

When using the `<a4j:support>` like described in the [RichFaces example](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_support.html#d0e7173) I'm always getting the following error when changing the value of the drop-down-box.

> Expected a child component type of UISelectItem/UISelectItems for
>   component type javax.faces.SelectOne(myId). Found null.

Here's the JSF code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectId" valueChangeListener="#{cs.myListener}" value="#{cs.selectList.selectedItem}">
 <f:selectItems value="#{cs.bundeslandList.selectItems}" />
 <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="otherFieldId" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="otherFieldId">
 <f:selectItems value="#{cs.bundeslandList.selectOtherField.selectItems}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Since `cs.bundeslandList.selectOtherField.selectItems` is at least an empty `ArrayList`, I'm certain that `otherFieldId`can't be `null`.

---

I've stripped down now the whole page and I'm no longer getting the error. The `valueChangeListener` is called correctly **but** unfortunately, the `otherFieldId` won't be refreshed after the call. It's emptied. But when debugging I can see that the corresponding property is filled with entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The getter of `<f:selectItems value>` has at some point definitely returned `null`. There's no other reason for this exception. Likely your backing bean code logic flow is plain wrong.

Note that making this property `static` is a very bad idea. It's going to be shared among all other requests on the entire web application. You want to make it request based or at highest session based.

Comment: That's a different problem and should technically go in a new question. First step would be to elaborate what exactly you mean with "won't be refreshed". Wasn't it ajax re-rendered? Or did the `<f:selectItems>` getter just return an empty list?

Comment: It was re-rendered, but now it's empty. But I don't know why, since the property is definitely filled.

Comment: So, you have put a breakpoint on the getter method and it returned a filled list during render response?

Comment: Yes. I've even debugged into the JSF library. There it's also filled.

Comment: That can only mean that it's actually not re-rendered at all. With Firebug you should be able to track the changes in HTML DOM tree.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4719/discussion-between-bernhard-v-and-balusc)