# Expected a child component type of UISelectItem/UISelectItems for component type javax.faces.SelectOne(underwriters)

Tags: jsf, javabeans

```
 <tr>
  <td width="20%"></td>
   <td align="left">
<h:outputText value="#{PeerReviewBean.underwriters}"/>:
   </td>
  <td align="left">
  <h:selectOneMenu id="underwriters" styleClass="selectmedium_dropdown">
         <f:selectItems value="#{PeerReviewBean.underwriters}"/>
                       </h:selectOneMenu> </td>
```

I 'm getting the following  error in above mentioned code:Expected a child component type of UISelectItem/UISelectItems for component type javax.faces.SelectOne(underwriters). Found null.  How can I solve this error?

Comment: `h:selectOneMenu` needs a `value` attribute. Check out [selectOneMenu info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info).

Comment: @eljunior: that's not required and is also not what the exception suggests.

Comment: @BalusC I know that the attribute isn't required, but isn't the result of `value` necessary for conversion to work?

Comment: Duplicates earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008955/jsf-error-expected-a-child-component-type-found-null

Answer (score 5):

You can get this exception when `#{PeerReviewBean.underwriters}` in the particular code snippet has returned `null`. Fix your backing bean code accordingly so that it never returns `null`.